# final variable initialization in subClass

Tags: java

```
public class A {

    final int  x;

    public A(int x) {
        if ( this instanceof B ) {
            if(x > 5)
                this.x = x;
            else
                this.x = 0;
        } else {
            this.x = 0;
        }

    }   
}

public class B extends A {

    public B(int x) {
        super(x); 
    }
}
```

I want to put the if in the class B to avoid instanceof ( because i have more sub classes and the x value depends on the subClass ), but when i do that i get compiler error: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor!

Can you help me avoid instanceof?

Comment: `super(x > 5 ? x : 0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways we can initialize constants, first one is to initialize them in place on the same line as in the answer by Adam, second is to use constructors, which you're trying to implement.

Using inline initialization is generally more flexible because we are not bound to the rules of the constructor, like `this(...)` or `super(...)` call should be the first in the constructor. However if you do want to use constructor for the purpose you can use method containing logic as inline call as argument to the `this(...) or super(...)`. This method should be `static` as the instance of the class doesn't exist yet as we're in constructor. Following is a simple solution for the same.

```
class A {

    final int  x;

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = 0;
    }   
}

class B extends A {

    public B(int x) {
        super(getValueForX(x));
    }

    private static int getValueForX(int x) {

        return x > 5 ? x : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `abstract` method in `A` and implement it in your derived classes like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    final int x;

    abstract int calculateX(int x);

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = calculateX(x);
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    int calculateX(int x) {
        return x + 1;
    }

    public B(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't invoke overridable methods from subclasses in constructors. Aside from being unsafe, this is just convoluted: `B` is passing an int into a method (a special method, the ctor, but still a method), which turns around, passing that int back to the `B` for it to calculate another int. Or... just pass that int in the first place.

Comment: I know it leaks `this` but this is a solution for the question.

Comment: No, it's not that it leaks `this`, it's that you're invoking an instance method on an uninitialized instance. If the method depends upon any state (now, or in the future), this may return an unexpected result.

Comment: This only causes problems if you don't know what you are doing.